# How to horizontally use inline-block with 3 div tags

Tags: html, css, display

I'm currently have these 3 `div` tags and trying to aline them to full 100% width. But I can't seem to get the 2nd and 3rd `div` to aline with the 1st `div`. I'm not sure what the issue is with the first `div`.

Currently learning how CSS interacts with HTML, any explanation is greatly appreciated.

**The Code (http://jsfiddle.net/Jenz/hs6ptm1t):**

```css
.widget_opening_hours{
  display:inline-block;
}
.widget_address{
  display:inline-block;
}
.widget_nav_menu{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget_opening_hours">
  <h3 class="hours-title">Business Hours:</h3>
  <div class="day"> 
    <span class="left"> Sunday: </span>
    <span class="right">CLOSED </span>
  </div>
  <div class= "day">
    <span class="left"> Monday: </span>
    <span class="right>"> CLOSED </span>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <span class="left"> Tuesday: </span>
    <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
  </div>
  <div class="day"> 
    <span class="left"> Wednesday: </span>
    <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <span class="left"> Thursday:</span>
    <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
  </div> 
  <div class="day">
    <span class="left"> Friday: </span>
    <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <span class="left"> Saturday: </span>
    <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="widget_address">
  <h3 class="address-title">Address:</h3>
  <div class="address"><p>25 Mulberry Lane,<br>Rainy Grove,
    <br>Cranberry State,<br>United States of JGE23</p></div>
</div>
<div class="widget_nav_menu">
  <a href="#home"> Home </a><br>
  <a href="#cakesicings">Cakes & Icings</a><br>
  <a href="#scakes">Specialty Cakes</a><br>
  <a href="#ccakes">Cupcakes</a><br>
  <a href="#cookies">Cookies</a><br>
  <a href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.widget_opening_hours{
width: 33.33%;
float:left;
}

.widget_address{
    text-align: center;
width: 33.33%;
float:left;
}

.widget_nav_menu{
    text-align: center;
width: 33.33%;float:left;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that using `display: inline-block` will do nothing if used with `float: left`

Comment: "aline them to full 100% width"  you can use float and width to resolve this problem @Morpheus I make a corretion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a grid of some sort then do the following.

Add `font-size: 0;` to your parent element, and then add `width:33.33%;` to your "columns".

In this example I create a col-3 class that I added to your three content containers.

```css
body {
  font-size: 0;
}

.widget_opening_hours{
display:inline-block;
 }

.widget_address{
display:inline-block;
text-align: center;
 }

.widget_nav_menu{
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
 <div class=" col-3 widget_opening_hours">
        <h3 class="hours-title">Business Hours:</h3>
            <div class="day">   
                <span class="left"> Sunday: </span>
                    <span class="right">CLOSED </span>
            </div>
            <div class= "day">
                <span class="left"> Monday: </span>
                    <span class="right>"> CLOSED </span>
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                <span class="left"> Tuesday: </span>
                     <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
            </div>
            <div class="day"> 
                <span class="left"> Wednesday: </span>
                    <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                <span class="left"> Thursday:</span>
                    <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
            </div>  
            <div class="day">
                <span class="left"> Friday: </span>
                    <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                <span class="left"> Saturday: </span>
                    <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
            </div>
    </div> 

<div class="col-3 widget_address">
  <h3 class="address-title">Address:</h3>
<div class="address"><p>25 Mulberry Lane,<br>Rainy Grove,
 <br>Cranberry State,<br>United States of JGE23</p></div>
</div>

<div class="col-3 widget_nav_menu">
    <a href="#home"> Home </a><br>
    <a href="#cakesicings">Cakes & Icings</a><br>
    <a href="#scakes">Specialty Cakes</a><br>
    <a href="#ccakes">Cupcakes</a><br>
    <a href="#cookies">Cookies</a><br>
    <a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were closing your footer before you call the rest of the inline divs. Moving the closing `div` at the end of the snippet does the job for you. Check it also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hs6ptm1t/4/).

```
<div class="footer area_right"> 
        <div class="widget_opening_hours">
            <h3 class="hours-title">Business Hours:</h3>

                <div class="day">   
                    <span class="left"> Sunday: </span>
                        <span class="right">CLOSED </span>
                </div>
                <div class= "day">
                    <span class="left"> Monday: </span>
                        <span class="right>"> CLOSED </span>
                </div>
                <div class="day">
                    <span class="left"> Tuesday: </span>
                         <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
                </div>
                <div class="day"> 
                    <span class="left"> Wednesday: </span>
                        <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
                </div>
                <div class="day">
                    <span class="left"> Thursday:</span>
                        <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
                </div>  
                <div class="day">
                    <span class="left"> Friday: </span>
                        <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
                </div>
                <div class="day">
                    <span class="left"> Saturday: </span>
                        <span class="right"> 8am-5pm </span>
                </div>

        </div> 


        <div class="widget_address">
            <h3 class="address-title">Address:</h3>
            <div class="address"><p>25 Mulberry Lane,<br>Rainy Grove,<br>Cranberry State,<br>United States of JGE23
            </p></div>
        </div>                                  

        <div class="widget_nav_menu">
                <a href="#home"> Home </a>
                    <br>
                <a href="#cakesicings">Cakes & Icings</a> 
                    <br>
                <a href="#scakes">Specialty Cakes</a> 
                    <br>
                <a href="#ccakes">Cupcakes</a> 
                    <br>
                <a href="#cookies">Cookies</a> 
                    <br>
                <a href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```